# WebSphere portal createActionURL from Servlet

Tags: servlets, websphere-portal

Using an E-mail from our CMS a user is requested to click on a confirm link which guides them to a Servlet on our Websphere Portal Server.

The user should be redirected to a portlet which shows them a success or failure message. From portlet to portlet I would create an action Url, add params and redirect the user. What would be the proper way to do this from a servlet?

Creating an action url requires a MimeResponse / RenderResponse, not a HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the helper classes I created http://www.asponte.com/wps/portal/asponte/labs/blog-detail/portal%208.0%20and%208.5%20advanced%20url%20generation%20helper%20classes
and use either the servlet helper or offline helper
a few things to be aware of is that you cannot generate a url to an action phase of a portlet if that portlet/page requires authentication and you are generating the url before they have authenticated.  if you do not want to use them you can use the advanced url generation apis directly like this
Get the PortalStateManagerHome

```
 this.psmsHome =  ((PortalStateManagerServiceHome)ctx.lookup("portal:service/state/PortalStateManager"));
```

and the navigationselectionmodel

```
 this.navSelHome = 
 ((NavigationSelectionModelHome)ctx.lookup("portal:service/model/NavigationSelectionModel"));
```

Then from those, you can get the providers from the home
service = this.psmsHome.getPortalStateManagerService(request, response);
provider = this.navSelHome.getNavigationSelectionModelProvider();
then you would get the url like this

```
URLAccessorFactory urlFactory = 
      (URLAccessorFactory)mgr.getAccessorFactory(URLAccessorFactory.class);

    EngineURL url = urlFactory.newURL(request, response, mgr
      .newState(), Constants.EMPTY_COPY);

    SelectionAccessorFactory selectionFactory = 
      (SelectionAccessorFactory)mgr.getAccessorFactory(SelectionAccessorFactory.class);

    SelectionAccessorController selectionCtrl = selectionFactory
      .getSelectionAccessorController(url.getState());

    selectionCtrl.setSelection(pageName);

    selectionCtrl.dispose();
    if (portletName != null)
    {
      PortletAccessorFactory portletAccessorFactory = 
        (PortletAccessorFactory)mgr.getAccessorFactory(PortletAccessorFactory.class);

      PortletAccessorController portletCtrl = portletAccessorFactory
        .getPortletAccessorController(portletName, url.getState());

      Map parameters = portletCtrl.getParameters();
      if (params != null)
      {
        String key = null;
        Iterator paramsIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
        while (paramsIterator.hasNext())
        {
          key = (String)paramsIterator.next();
          parameters.put(key, params.get(key));
        }
      }
      portletCtrl.dispose();
    }
    return url.writeDispose(new StringWriter()).toString
```

that will let you target a portlet and pass in params
if you want to reach a specific action you will need to use the actionaccessorfactory